# How in Robot Framework get selector value from library in "Test Cases"

Tags: robotframework, pageobjects

guys.
I'm new in Robot Framework and may be my  question seems simple but I can't find right solution.

I have a test:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Login Scenarios
Library  ExtendedSelenium2Library
Library  Resources/LoginPage.py
Resource  Resources/Common.robot
Library  Resources/TopMenuPage.py
Suite Setup  Begin Web Test
Suite Teardown  End Web Test

*** Variables ***
${USERNAME}  user
${PASSWORD}  password

*** Test Cases ***
Login With Valid Credentials
  [Documentation]  Login With Valid Credentials
  [Tags]  Functional
  LoginPage.input_username   ${USERNAME}
  LoginPage.input_password   ${PASSWORD}
  LoginPage.click_sign_in_button
  ${test}  TopMenuPage.get_selectors
  page should contain link  ${test['logoutButton']}
  [Teardown]  click link  css=[ng-click="mainCtrl.logout()"]
```

And I have a my library (TopMenuPage.py) code:

```
selectors = {
    "logoutButton": "css=[ng-click=\"mainCtrl.logout()\"]",
    "welcome": "binding=mainCtrl.user.name"
}

class TopMenuPage(object):
    def get_selectors(self):
        return selectors
```

How, in right way, I can get my selectors in test?
For example:

```
page should contain link  TopMenuPage.get_selectors['logoutButton']
```

Thanks for response.

Comment: For now I use additional variable ${test} and it's work. But I think it's not good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `page should contain  TopMenuPage.get_selectors['logoutButton']` because `page should contain` requires a string as an argument, not a function call. You will need to call `TopMenuPage.get_selectors` and save the result in a variable, and then use the variable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a last question: Can I create a variable that will available in all Suite?
I tried to move ${test} variable to *** Variables *** but I got an ERROR - "Resolving variable '${test['logoutButton']}' failed: TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: @AlexanderMelnychuk"   yes, robot supports test, suite and global variables. It's all documented in the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-set-test-suite-global-variable-keywords).